# What are the descriptons for Huawei AdsKit AdListener.onAdFailed error codes?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

What are the descriptions for Huawei AdsKit [AdListener.onAdFailed](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/ads-api-adlistener#onAdFailed) error codes?

It works as expected in test mode, but not in production. I'm getting `onAdFailed(3)` : `I/HiAdSDK.h:  onAdFailed, errorCode:700` in the log for banner ads and `I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager:  onAdFailed, errorCode:204` for interstitial ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I've found the explanation in [FAQ](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ads-sdk-faq).
To be more detailed about code 3:

> The ad request is successful, but the server does not return any available ad material.

Also there are predefined [enum values](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/ads-api-adparam-errorcode).

Comment: Error code 700 indicates that the native ad request fails. You can run this command to return the complete log, ```adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.huawei.hwid/files/Log/HiAdKitLog.log ./.``` Then plz provide the log to check for more information. :)

Comment: @shirley attached the files in the [ticket comments](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ads-demo-java/issues/10#issuecomment-759260292)

Answer (score 0):

Error code 3 indicates that the ad request is successful, but the server does not return available ad assets. Check whether the ad slot ID takes effect and whether the test mobile phone is connected to the correct network. Alternatively, you can contact the customer service personnel.